# How to set a fallback image for img setAttribute

Tags: javascript, image, setattribute

I have an img element:

```
var photo = document.createElement("img");
```

which is feed by photos with name stored in an array of objects, so I "feed" the photos like this:

```
photo.setAttribute('src', './pics/' + myarray[id].Name + '.jpg');
```

And it works perfect.

The only thing not working is to set an attribute with a default photo for the element that don't have a pic.

I have tried to do a `setAttribute` line above that one, setting a "default" picture for all the elements, hoping that the second line would replace with proper picture the elements that have one, and leave the default ones untouched, but no... `console.log` still showed a message of expecting a `name+jpg` scheme, it totally ignored my previous line (so I am pretty sure is not how it works).

So if you have an `img` element with many instances through an array, what is the best way to assign a default picture to the elements whose picture is not specified in purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use jQuery. This is a solution for the problem you described. If an image comes back as a 404 then it gets the default image applied

http://jsfiddle.net/gunderson/D3DSt/

```
var photo = document.createElement("img");
photo.setAttribute("id", "myPhoto");
$('body').append(photo);

$("#myPhoto").attr("src", 'alogo3w.png').error(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png");
  })
​
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! It didn't work, because `myarray[id].Name` is also true in the second case, is just that a pic doesn't exist for it.

Comment: What is the value of myarray[id].Name when a pic doesn't exist?

Comment: It will be user input, so it could be anything. The example is: When the picture exist, it's because is a product created by me, so I have a photo with the proper name. If the pic doesn't exist, it's a product whose name is user input... the array keeps being normal, but I just don't have a photo of it, so I was hoping to find out a way to specify "put this default picture when the user inputted name doesn't match with any of the pictures you have stored".

Comment: I am not so good with jQuery, but I think this is the same as regular JS: `photo.onerror`? It's a good point, I think is just what I need!

Comment: perhaps. I use jQuery to handle things like that because they take care of most cross-browser issues you may run into.

Answer (score 1):

Just set only the default if neccessary

```
photo.setAttribute('src', './pics/' + ( myarray[id].Name ? myarray[id].Name : 'default' ) + '.jpg');
```